# Need help installing new sub panel

Tags: electrical, subpanel

ok I have included pictures to help, The first picture is of the main panel and if you see at the top left it's labeled sub feed and it's 70 amp breaker that 70 amp breaker powers the second picture.

So what I'm trying to do is rip out everything that you see in the second picture and install a new sub panel but as you can see there are some issues.

Currently the system is set to low voltage and you can see the solenoids each one of those solenoids ties to a light switch.

The former owner of the house had set up a control all lights from the master bedroom location and that's one of the pictures included.

I've also included pictures of how the switches are wired so my question is how do I go about setting this up?

Do I bring in the new panel and just run new wire do I try to use the wire that's currently there?

Seems to be a very unique setup. The former owner of the house worked for the power company so he was an expert and just any help here's greatly appreciated because it seems to me I've seen some people change out the fuse box panel but never have I seen something where it was connected to a low voltage transformer with solenoids and I wanna make sure that everything works correctly but I don't know that I can get everything to work correctly in its current state So what is the best thing I can do thank you everybody for your help in advance.
[image: main panel the 70 amp subfeed on the left top]

[image: feeds this picture]
[image: another angle]
[image: a picture of the whole old panel]
[image: main control]
[image: how switches are wired]

Comment: Looks like the "expert" was suffering from some "experts can ignore code" false beliefs on what appears to be the line voltage part of this mess. No cable clamps on knockouts, etc. And definitely not done in a neat and professional manner.

Comment: i agree, exactly, any help you can provide here is great because I have to figure out how best to do this because it looks like it could get so complicated

Comment: Just because the former owner worked for the power company doesn't automatically qualify him as an expert electrician. I work for a hospital system, but _trust me_ you do _NOT_ want me performing your next surgery!

Comment: lol i hear you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the switch wiring for line voltage, since it appears to be run as unprotected individual wires (not cables and not in conduit) so you either use that system as is (low voltage only) (or as neatened up) or you're rewiring every switch.

The line voltage part of this has blatant code violations in sight. I'm assuming the lights themselves are line voltage, not low voltage? Does not appear that the line voltage wiring of the relays (what you call solenoids - a related, but different item) meets code as is either. But perhaps the lights are low voltage? I'm skeptical.

I can see individual hot and switched hot wires running unprotected between the relay boxes and the fusebox. That's never acceptable.

If using the relays, the low voltage wiring should be disentangled from the line voltage wiring and there should be conduits from the new breaker box into the lower part of each relay box. Those need covers, as well, unless you just took them off for the pictures.

If not using the relays, you're going to be rewiring much of the house to get back to somethng useable.

Comment: thank you for this! how would i check line voltage? but just by what you said I would agree they are probably running line voltage, but how would i check?                                           as you mentioned, i need to re wire the whole thing to every switch with new wires? looks like i can still use the feed from the main and connect that in and then start wiring everything up the issue with that is that all the switches in the house run off that mess of wires. If you need any more pictures or need me to test something please let me know

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter? And/or, can you read a lightbulb? Which will tell you without needing the voltmeter. Wattage and voltage are usually printed right on them.

Comment: i do have voltmeter, but the lights are just 60 or 100w led bulbs